# PHP DateTime Functions

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3

I have the following code fragment:

```
$now = '2011-12-01 22:32:33';
$datetime = '2011-12-01 00:07:27';  


$nowObj = new DateTime($now);
$datetimeObj = new DateTime($datetime);

$diff = $datetimeObj->diff($nowObj); //leaving this in screws up the next line

number_format(1134); //this becomes NaN
```

When I am running through this code and leave the $diff = ... line in, it messes with other numbers and math that I do later in the code.  For instance, my number_format(1134); later on becomes NaN. I am using a XAMPP stack with PHP 5.3.1.  Is this a bug?

Comment: mmm... can you add the "mess" code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could [this be related](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51755), hmm ...

If you are on windows, I would make sure time zone settings are set correctly. The comments on php.net point out a couple of quirks and buggy behavior under windows, maybe seriously consider using an alternate method for diffing your dates if issues persist.

Comment: awesome, its always only the next operation that breaks, i've had this bug for awhile

Comment: No problem, they point to a bugfix in that post, if the fix does not work or your php version is more recent, please consider posting back on that board your finding, or re-opening an issue on this? It would help make php better.  Or, at least the date object, maybe. :o)

Answer (score 0):

It seem a *locale* problem.
hev you set the timezone in **php.ini**?

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Rome
```

Europe/Rome is my timezone ;)

or you can also add

```
ini_set("date.timezone","Europe/Rome");
```

in your code